# Enforce equal amount of days each quarter R 'xts'

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, xts, midasr

Suppose I have the following data set:

Daily observations of the S&P500, and
Quarterly Total Public Debt.
The observation of the quarter is at time

```
xxxx-01-01
xxxx-04-01
xxxx-07-01
xxxx-10-01
```

The non trading days such as weekend and holidays are denoted with NAs

```
2020-01-01 NA
2020-01-02 3257.85
2020-01-02 3234.85
.
.
.
.
2020-03-31 2584.59
```

This will yield an unequal amount of observation per quarter.
MY question is how do I remove a certain amount of dates such that within each quarter I will have exactly 66 observations of the S&P500?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the index to `yearqtr` (from `zoo`), use that to create a logical index for first 66 observations

```
xt1[ave(seq_along(index(xt1)), as.yearqtr(index(xt1)), FUN = 
        seq_along) <= 66]
```

---

As @G.Grothendieck mentioned in the comments, the idea would be to first remove the NA elements

```
xt2 <- na.omit(xt1)
```

then, calculate the `min`imum number of elements per each quarter

```
n <- min(tapply(seq_along(index(xt1)), as.yearqtr(index(xt1)), FUN = length))
```

Use that in first code block

```
xt2[ave(seq_along(index(xt2)), as.yearqtr(index(xt2)), FUN = 
        seq_along) <= n]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233142/discussion-on-answer-by-akrun-enforce-equal-amount-of-days-each-quarter-r-xts).